# Azure SQL Database Data Deleted

Tags: azure-sql-database

If I deleted any data in Azure SQL Database,is permanently deleted or not?Where can I find my deleted data?I don't want to restore for a few data.Is there any solution

I already tried backup and restore.But now I don't want to use restore process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no direct way to restore specific data from the backup in Azure SQL database. We need to restore the backup to new database and then can copy this specific deleted data back to original database.